# Autohotkey / AHK - String as function parameter without " "

Tags: autohotkey

Is there any way to define function parameter as string by default, so I could send them without using double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know C++ and want to compile your own version of AHK from the source code, or if you want to make an other script which will insert in the quotes automatically after the fact, then yes. Otherwise no.
And I really don't know why you'd want to do this. Seems terrible in my opinion.
Maybe you're used to legacy AHK? If so, you really should let go of that. Maybe about 10 years ago it was fine to use.